# string compare doesn't working ! language is python

Tags: python, list, compare

```
import hashlib
import os

dir_path = input("Input directory : ") + "/"
hashset_path = input("Input hashset directory (ex: C:/../user/hashset.txt) : ")
hash_type = int(input("1:MD5 2.SHA-1 3.SHA-256\n choose hash : "))

if hash_type == 1:
    hash_type = "md5"
elif hash_type == 2:
    hash_type = "sha1"
elif hash_type == 3:
    hash_type = "sha256"
else:
    print("somethig is wrong")
    exit()

temp = getattr(hashlib, hash_type)


f1 = open(hashset_path,'r',encoding='UTF-8')
lines = f1.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()  
f1.close()


# compare file
file_lst = os.listdir(dir_path)
count = 0
matchedfile = []
for file in file_lst:
    filepath = dir_path + file

    f = open(filepath, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    for n in range(0,len(lines)):
        if (str(temp(data).hexdigest()) == str(lines[n])): 
            matchedfile.append("filename : " + file + " " + "calculated hash : " + temp(data).hexdigest() + " " + "hash of hashset.txt : " + lines[n])
            count += 1


if count == 0:
    print("no matched hash")
else:
    for i in range(0,len(matchedfile)):
        print(matchedfile[i])
```

What is the problem in my code?
`if (str(temp(data).hexdigest()) == str(lines[n])):`
this code is not working.. even both string is perfectly same!
how can i do..

Comment: This code calculate the hash list in the hashset.txt file and the hashes of the files in the directory and compares them.

Comment: What does "not working" actually mean? what does it do?

Comment: Even though the hash values ​​are the same, the return value of the comparison operator is 0, meaning that the statements executed when the hash values ​​are the same are not executed normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be reading from a text file. Please be aware that this process includes the line endings which you don't in fact strip off:

```py
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
```

The above snippet of code does nothing except waste time.

You meant to write this:

```py
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

Comment: Thanks! It work!
I'm new to Stack OverFlow and thanks for the kindly correct answer.